# How many skill points are available in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Lets say you've completed 100% of the game's skill challenges.

How many skill points would you have by the end of it?

Is there any other way to get skill points excluding Skill Challenges?

Comment: Remember that you continue to level after reaching 80, earning a skill point each time. Skill points are infinite; you don't have to worry about not getting all the skills.

Comment: One of those 4 in 1 questions.

Comment: @danRhul Edited Question removing all the inner questions, could you please, undo your -1 please.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ways to earn [skill points](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Skill_point) are:

> - Completing a skill challenge
> - Leveling up, starting at level 5
> - Past level 80, for every 254,000 experience points earned.
> - Dessa's Experimental Journal (purchased for 35 Fractal Relics)

There were 202 skill challenges at launch time, according to the [official wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Skill_challenge).

The amount of skill points you would have by the time you found all skill challenges will depend on your total experience by then. Like [Raven Dreamer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer) [said](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94392/how-many-skill-points-are-available-in-guild-wars-2#comment128917_94392), skill points are virtually infinite.

Comment: So, just to summarize, there are infinite skill points available, theoretically of course.

Comment: You can see the total number of skill challenges, hearts, waypoints, POIs and vistas in the top left corner of the map under world completion. If they ever add more, it should update this number.